# Video game with a black female police officer who starts out fighting gangs, but then fights "Men in Black" with sci-fi weapons, and eventually demons

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I played this at least 15 years ago on a Windows PC, installed from CDs. The protagonist is a black woman who is a police officer in a large city. I remember some of the early bits were tutorials for how to arrest suspects, and a driving section that included having to accelerate to a particular speed, and then decelerate to hit a particular zone.

The gameplay was third-person 3D graphics, more overhead than over-the-shoulder. There were both guns and melee combat, as well as the ability to use vehicles. If you got injured, you started leaving a blood trail that enemies could follow.

Early on, you're dealing with regular crooks and gang members, but later in the game, you encounter "Men in Black" enemies wielding sci-fi weapons and able to take inhuman amounts of punishment and late parts of the game, if I recall correctly, have you battling demons summoned by one of the gang leaders.

I don't think I actually finished the game, but I have a vague memory of reading a bit about it from a strategy guide, and learning that the final boss refers to the protagonist as "a Nubian warrior" to emphasize his prejudices.

Comment: It is definitely Urban Chaos. DavidW is correct. And your initial description was very good!

Comment: So they're not actually fighting "Men in Black", but space aliens?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is probably [Urban Chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urban_Chaos). Quoting the summary on Wikipedia:

> The story begins with D'arci Stern, the protagonist, joining the Union City Police Department. Much of her time is spent dealing with the Wildcats, a **gang** that is getting increasingly bold in their criminal activity. With the help of a vigilante named Roper McIntyre, D'arci begins to believe that the Wildcats plan to take over Union City. As the Wildcats grow ever bolder, D'arci discovers that the gang is led by Mack Bane, a candidate for mayor of Union City. Eventually, the Wildcats attempt a hostile takeover of the city, which is finally repelled by D'arci, Roper and the police.
>
> Some time later, D'arci is investigating a particularly brutal murder. She discovers that the murder was committed by Bane's elite bodyguards, a brotherhood of **mysterious men in tailored black suits** known as "The Fallen". This establishes a connection between Bane, the Wildcats and the Fallen. Soon after, he is arrested by D'arci and Roper in his out-of-town estate. Even from jail, Bane is able to direct the Wildcats, and D'arci and Roper are forced to deal with several more threats to the city. Later, Bane breaks out of jail and claims to be an Ancient Warlock. He uses his powers to summon **a fire beast known as a Baalrog**, which attempts to destroy the city, but D'arci and Roper defeat it. Bane and the Wildcats flee to a sanctuary tower to fulfill a prophecy; before they can complete their ritual, D'arci and Roper must rescue injured civilians, battle the remnants of the Wildcats and Fallen, and use the tower's ventilation system to destroy Bane once and for all.

It's a 1999 PC game with a 3rd-person perspective, so it seems to match your requirements.  I never actually played it myself; I just had a mate who showed it to me once.  (Before he got heavily into MMOs.)

Comment: That does look right. Thank you.